# Gathering a value from a column from each row from a table into an array in protractor

Tags: angularjs, promise, protractor

Writing e2e tests for an Angular App, but I don't seem to be able to get my head around async programming and promises.
I'm attempting to get the value from each row, from the first column and add that to an array to eventually sort it from high to low to have the highest value.
I'm having some trouble resolving the promise of my rows.each, the errormsg is:
'TypeError: undefined is not a function'

```
//This function will fetch the highest ID from the columns
this.getHighestScheduleId = (function(){
    //Array to collect the ID's in
    var idArray = [];
    //Collects all the rows in our table
    var rows = $$('#schedulesData');
    //Goes through each row
    rows.each(function(row){
        //Collect all the row's elements in rowElems
        var rowElems = row.$$('td');
        console.log(rowElems[0].getText());
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the `$$` function? My suggestion is to look at the `row` variable and make sure it has `$$` method as well. It may be a HTMLElement, which does not have that method.

Comment: The $$ is short for element.all(by.css('#schedulesData'); and the row.$$('td') is getting filled up as well, the expects are showing me correct values in the log but when I try to print them directly they are still undefined.

Comment: So the question is, which function is the JS engine evaluating as `undefined`? I see a few candidates: `$$`, `rows.each`, `row.$$`, `rowElems.count`, `rowElems.get`, `rowElems.get(0).getText`.
Try to figure out which line is causing that error.

Comment: Edit: the rowElems.get was causing a hickup for JS, changed it to rowElems[0] instead of rowElems.get(0).  Now the .getText() is throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) would fit nicely here:

```
rows.each(function(row) {
    var rowElems = row.all('td').map(function (td) {
        return td.getText();
    });

    // resolve the promise to see the output on the console
    rowElems.then(function (values) {
        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the source to map(). Was able to broaden my understanding key-value pairs.